# How to dynamically change directive's templateUrl in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to dynamically change directive's templateUrl and compile it?

```
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
      return 'customer-'+attr.type+'.html';
    }
  };
});
```

And the html is like:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <button> Change my customer template</button>
    <my-customer></my-customer>
</div>
```

This is the code from Angular Doc, say if I want to click that button to change myCustomer template, how can I do that?

Comment: Yes you can, and the instructions to do so are in the developer guide to directives (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  If you would like a more specific answer, you should provide some code showing what you have tried.

Comment: @Claies Thanks, could you point out which section on that page is related to change templateUrl?

Comment: you mean the section that says "templateUrl can also be a function which returns the URL of an HTML template to be loaded and used for the directive"?

Comment: @Claies Yes, could you tell me how can I called it dynamically, other than the initial stage?

Comment: by passing a parameter to the directive that is evaluated by the function that generates the templateUrl.  If you want any more specific than that, you'll have to supply some code.

Comment: @Claies Thanks, I have updated my question

Comment: that's the JavaScript from the angular documentation, but definitely not the supporting HTML for that same example;  That's the HTML from one of the other examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101139/discussion-between-kuan-and-claies).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below code. templateUrl is the HTML Url.

```
 template = $templateCache.get(templateUrl);
    if (typeof template === "undefined") {
        $http.get(templateUrl)
          .success(function (data) {
              $templateCache.put(templateUrl, data);
              def.resolve(data);
          }).error(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
    } else {
        def.resolve(template);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, could you show me how to use this $templateCache to change specific Directive template

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('panelDir', ['$templateCache', '$http', '$q', '$compile', function ($templateCache, $http, $q, $compile) {

var getTemplate = function (contentType) {
    var def = $q.defer();
    var template = '';
    var templateUrl = "";

    switch (contentType) {
        case 'setting':
            templateUrl = "Panel.html";
            break;
    }        
    template = $templateCache.get(templateUrl);
    if (typeof template === "undefined") {
        $http.get(templateUrl)
          .success(function (data) {
              $templateCache.put(templateUrl, data);
              def.resolve(data);
          }).error(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
    } else {
        def.resolve(template);
    }

    return def.promise;
}

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {           
        getTemplate(attrs['paneltype']).then(function (data) {
            data = $compile(data)(scope);
        });
    }
  }
});
```